# Pros and cons of using WebAssembly + Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, webassembly, blazor

My questions are:

- Is runtime downloaded every time SPA is opened? Even if it is cached, won't downloading runtime take way too much time for web app?
- Are additional assemblies (Nuget, C++ libs, etc) sent to browser? If so, isn't that too size-expensive and won't it cause an app to open way too long?
- Is performance better enough comparing to Javascript on V8?
- Are there any breathtaking differences comparing to Razor?

And, answering all these questions, are there any reasons to use Blazor+Wasm over Javascript?

Comment: The 'runtime'  is about 2.5 MB, it will vary whether that's a problem. For the other performance factors it is too early, Blazor is still in beta. But expect it to be at least as fast as a JS framework.

Comment: The main reason for using Blazor will probably be: no JavaScript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are multiple questions which you could have googled with little effort and I assume people downvoted you for it. I will take the time to answer your questions.

> Is runtime downloaded every time SPA is opened? Even if it is cached, won't downloading runtime take way too much time for web app?

As you can read on [webassembly.org](https://webassembly.org/), webassembly (further referred to as `Wasm`) is a binary instruction format for a stack-based virtual machine with an open API and shipped to Chrome, Edge, Firefox and WebKit. As @HenkHolterman mentioned, there is a small runtime that needs to be loaded by the clients at least once, unless they clear their cache. This means that there might be a worse experience the first time a client will load a `Wasm` based web application, how bad this experience is, I can’t tell exactly, 2,5 mb using Fibre is not remarkable, using edge/2g or gsm/3g mobile connection might be significant.

> Are additional assemblies (Nuget, C++ libs, etc) sent to browser? If so, isn't that too size-expensive and won't it cause an app to open way too long?

When you build / compile your `Blazor` application, you usually restore all dependent assemblies and packages and these are hosted statically on the host after a deployment. The clients will not need any additional assemblies.

> Is performance better enough comparing to Javascript on V8?

That depends. `Wasm` is currently not aware of the DOM and so `Blazor`rerenders Pages using `Wasm`, whenever needed. It should be clear that manipulation of single or few DOM elements within large pages will be faster with `JavaScript`. Other than that `Wasm` is faster at rendering whole pages and might fit best in web applications which need this performance, like gaming or 3d rendering. The difference is too small for normal browsing experience and will be bad using either if the application design is bad.

> Are there any breathtaking differences comparing to Razor?

`Blazor` is a framework rather focused on application delivery, while `Razor Pages` was introduced as a new `.Net`development method in contrast to MVC. Now `Blazor` uses a very similar syntax as `Razor`, simplifying things like event calls and unifying the view and code in one file, but the main difference is really the fact that `Blazor` can be serve-rside or client-side, while `Razor` can only serve the first. This is what you would take in consideration when deciding between the two.

That being said, you should know that WebAssembly is not trying to replace JavaScript, as described in their [FAQ](https://webassembly.org/docs/faq/), it is designed to be a complement to it. To decide whether to use `Blazor` over any `JavaScript` Framework depends on the whether you want a dependency to `JavaScript` or not and if your development team is more confident with `C#` and the `.Net` stack and lifecycle.

Comment: I think the 'runtime' here is Mono.wasm, and yes that needs to be downloaded (to the cache) at least once.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thx for the hint, wasn’t aware of it, I am looking it up

Comment: Nit: official spelling is Wasm, not WASM, see homepage. It's not an acronym, no reason to shout it. ;)

Comment: I was just in rage mode :D

Comment: Thank you. That helped me understand Wasm a lot. Sorry for question format, I just wanted an answer to “Is Blazor > JS” and wanted to make sure that answer will consider all these clauses